# How can rewrite this query for using with commonly used lat-long values

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have this query to get the nearest road vertices from a bus stop point. Ho can a re-write this query to pass commonly used lat-long values like in google maps instead of  715127 957625

```
SELECT * FROM tvm_city_busroute_vertices_pgr 
ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(715127 957625)',4326) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The coordinates in your question are not in SRID 4326 (WGS84). Just substitute those values for latitude and longitude values?

Comment: But don't forget to supply the SRID for web mercator (3857 Google). Those numbers do not match WGS84 (SRID 4326) - they should be in the range of -180 to 180, -90 to 90.

Comment: You can also use, eg, from the above, `ST_Transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(715127 957625)', 3857), 4326)`. Note that the coordinates you have are 3857, aka, Web Mercator, as used in Google Maps, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(715127 957625)',4326)
```

with

```
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(715127 957625)'),SRID_YOU_ARE_USING),4326)
```

4326 is the SRID of WGS84, which is used by GPS, and is the commonly used lat-lng system you're looking for.